# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable (python decorators)

Tags: python, python-decorators

i am getting `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` error when using `get_frame_work()`. how can i fix it?

```
import sys


def main(frame_work):
    if frame_work() == "selenium":
        pass
    elif frame_work() == "puppeteer":
        pass
    elif frame_work() == "play_wright":
        pass
    else:
        raise Exception("Invalid command!")


@main
def get_frame_work():
    return str(sys.argv[1].lower())


get_frame_work() #get_frame_work does not give an error unlike get_frame_work().
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decorator needs to return the actual function object that is wrapping the decorated function. Modifying your `main` like this will make it work.

```py
import sys


def main(frame_work):
    def f(): 
        if frame_work() == "selenium":
            pass
        elif frame_work() == "puppeteer":
            pass
        elif frame_work() == "play_wright":
            pass
        else:
            raise Exception("Invalid command!")
    return f
```